# Local dev server infinite load - vite, windows, chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, vite

90% of the time, after a refresh on the page with the devtools open, the local devserver does not load. Keep pending ruquests, no error. I have to close devtools, the open it again when it started to load to see actual data.

Vite, React, Windows, Chrome (but in all chromium browsers I guess)

Comment: Same for me for the past month. This is VERY frustrating.